# Negotiate with Cookie Fallback in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-identity

I have a setup as described in the title consisting of a default policy containing a requirement that can be fulfilled through a respective handler:

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationContext, AccessRequirement requirement)
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var identity = authorizationContext.User.Identity;

            if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var result = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync({"Negotiate || Cookie"});
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            authorizationContext.Succeed(requirement);
        }
```

As soon as I do not invoke these handlers through the default policy, the site will be displaying an simple 401 even if Negotiate authentication could be resolved. A way to solve this without handlers might actually solve the subsequent issue as well.
If i prioritize Negotiate (through explicitly setting default scheme or by registering it first) the user will be prompted for his Active Directory credentials if Negotiate is unavailable, while it should instead fall back to Cookie authentication.
However, if I prioritize Cookie authentication, the user will be prompted for his Cookie dedicated credentials even if Negotiate could work.

Is there any configuration that allows for some sort of try-catch mechanism to attempt Negotiate and immediately fall back to another scheme if it is unresolvable?
I tampered by setting different `DefaultChallengeScheme` parameters but was unsuccessful this far.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of 401: when u add service in startup:services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme). Here "JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme" is the name of the scheme to use by default when a specific scheme isn't requested. However, when an authentication challenge is invoked by Authorization,  a JWT bearer scheme returning a 401 result with a www-authenticate: bearer header.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If u wanna use multiple authentication methods u can try "AuthenticationSchemeOptions Class", inside the class has properties can be set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: That doesn't address my issue at all. I have already multiple authentication schemes registered, namely ÌdentityCookie` and `Negotiate`. The problem is that I can't check if the authentication may succeed (through a present cookie or NTLM) without immediately invoking the challenge prompt.